# Clarity Datagrid & Promise / Subject Bound Column

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have a data grid, with one column specifically that is bound to a function call.

```
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Id'">ID</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Client'">Client</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Name'" [clrDgSortOrder]="ClrDatagridSortOrder.ASC">Name</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'PublicKeyHash'">Public Key Hash</clr-dg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let clientLicense of ClientLicenses" [clrDgItem]="clientLicense">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Id}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>
      {{getClientName(clientLicense.ClientId)}}
    </clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Name}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.PublicKeyHash}}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>
```

See the second column, where we call "getClientName(clientLicense.ClientId)". This method needs to run asynchronously; that is, upon request it will not immediately have a value. I'm a bit newer to Typescript / Angular, but I believe that I'm looking to return either a Promise or a BehaviorSubject (I've used these pretty extensively so far when retrieving records from my repositories by method call rather than binding / subscribing).

So, I've tried returning a Promise, BehaviorSubject, AsyncSubject all with the same result - the entire web browser locks hard and I have to end process (lol).

I understand that binding to a property, or pre-populating a property on my view model would be easiest; however due to architecture this isn't easy... I essentially have two separate repositories that are related via. foreign key; I'm pulling the client name from the client repository based on the client id on the license.

Below are a few variants of "getClientName(...)" that I've attempted. I've tried variants of calling in the HTML template (i.e. async on the promise, etc.). Any ideas?

BehaviorSubjuct

```
  public getClientName(id: string): BehaviorSubject<string> {
    var result: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("");

    this.clientRepo.getById(id).then(x => result.next(x.Name))

    return result;
  }
```

Promise

```
  public async getClientName(id: string): Promise<string> {
    var client: Client;

    client = await this.clientRepo.getById(id).then()

    var result: string = "";

    if (client) {
      result = client.Name;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the built in [Angular async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) work?

```
 <clr-dg-cell>{{getClientName(clientLicense.ClientId) | async}}</clr-dg-cell>
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track... I was able to get the sample working using Observables described at the end of the article - thanks!

I am still having issue in my scenario however - I have a feeling it has something to do with my promise resolution on "getById(...)" or the fact I'm performing this within the Obeservable. Same results - the entire browser locks / need to end process. If I pause code, it's typically in a resolve promise stack...

Comment: public getClientName(id: string): Observable<string> {
    var result: Observable<string> = new Observable<string>((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      this.clientRepo.getById(id).then(x => observer.next(x.Name));
      //observer.next("test");
    });

    return result;
  }

Comment: Can you post a simple stackblitz that recreate the issue? It helps me understand what’s going on when I can work with a real application. We keep starters here: https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: I was able to get it working with the column bound to a method returning Observable<string>. There were some underlying architectural issues with my repository / approach which this implementation brought light to. Thank you for the guidance!